# ¿Donde colocar la información que se muestra logueado en devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Quiero poner un calendario al que no sea posible acceder al menos que el usuario este logueado con la gema `devise` y no se en donde colocar ese código en las carpetas de `rails`.

Les dejo un ejemplo de lo que tengo en layouts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>EsteticaRails</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
      <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
      <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p> 
      <%= yield %>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Esto es lo que tengo en views:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y dentro de layouts: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay alguna manera de determinar los usuarios logueados en tiempo real con devise? Utilizo Ruby 5 –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumo que tu calendario es un código html que quieres agregar (no lo tengo muy claro, ya que no agregaste código que lo explique), entonces donde agregues tu calendario, podrías usar:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <!-- el html de tu calendario -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hay alguna manera de determinar los usuarios logueados en tiempo real con devise? Utilizo Ruby 5 –

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener claro que Rails trabaja el **MVC** y tienes que definir si la validación que quieres esta en la Vista o en el Controlador.

Si la validación la quieres en la vista y usas archivo.html.erb:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <!-- el html de tu calendario -->
<% end %>
```

Si la validación la quieres en la vista y usas archivo.html.haml:

```
- if user_signed_in?
    <!-- el html de tu calendario -->
```

Ahora bien si la validación la quieres hacer en el controlador, te invito a ver la gema [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) que te permite manejar las autorizaciones.

Comment: Hay alguna manera de determinar los usuarios logueados en tiempo real con devise? Utilizo Ruby 5